# Ajax blob type recognition javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, file, google-chrome, blob

I'm using javascript to download multiple files from a webpage.
I'm using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) to save the file and this method to download :

```
function downloadFile(url, success) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open('GET', url, true); 
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () { 
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (success) success(xhr.response);
    }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

}

together I'm using it like that :

```
downloadFile(imgurl, function(blob) {
saveAs(blob, "image" + item + ".jpeg");
});
```

but the problem is im not sure what is the image/video type and the links arent specifying them. (cant take extention from url there's none)

My main issue is recognition between videos and images, probably mp4/png but I **prefer being able to determine each file type so I can save it with its extention.**

thanks in advance

Comment: maybe you can use the [XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getResponseHeader)

Comment: In your callback function, you can examine `blob.type`. For png files, it's `image/png` while predictably, mp4 videos are reported as `video/mp4`. So, rather than `saveAs` being the first thing that you do, you should check `blob.type` and use this result to decide which extension to append to the filename. simples.

Comment: @enhzflep i argue the `blob.type` property could be not so reliable, it should be better to enforce content type from the server and read it. I don't know if the type enforced from the server is written in the type property, maybe i'll try later

Comment: @enhzflep is right, the `blob.type` property can is enforced by the server `response.contentType` if calling a webservice, or by the magic number if serving the file directly, so it's safe to use.